# Android adb can't find my Galaxy Note 10.1

Tags: android, adb, android-4.3-jelly-bean, galaxy-tab

For some reason `adb` doesn't list my Samsung Note 10.1 when I run `adb devices`. Not even when I restart `abd`:

```
C:\android-sdk\sdk\platform-tools>adb kill-server

C:\android-sdk\sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached

C:\android-sdk\sdk\platform-tools>
```

So it can't find my device.

I already installed `Samsung Kies` as many suggested. This should install all the needed drivers. I also see my Galaxy Note in "Device Manager". So I guess I have the correct drivers.

[image]

*(Admin is the Device Name of my tablet)*

---

I also enabled `USB Debugging` on my tablet. But still no luck...

Anyone any idea what else I could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MOBO ROBO` for android drivers ,it support all the devices.Download from the web and use it.
Kies for Samsung,`MOBO ROBO` support all the devices

Comment: Actually, MOBO ROBO did work for me... Although i'm not really sure what it installed. But since this is a simple dev machine I don't really care. Adb can find my device now.

Comment: congrats ,go ahead in developing